# How to get vertical scrollbar in highstock for heatmap chart

Tags: highcharts

For the heatmap chart I could get horizontal scrollbar, now I need vertical scrollbar, similar to the chart shown in the below link

http://jsfiddle.net/fj6d2/3076/

Below is my sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
<script>


$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'heatmap',
            marginTop: 40,
            marginBottom: 40
        },


        title: {
            text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas', 'Maria', 'Leon', 'Anna', 'Tim', 'Laura'],
            min:2
        },

        yAxis: {
            categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
            title: null,


        },
scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 0,
            minColor: '#FFFFFF',
            maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        },

        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            layout: 'vertical',
            margin: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            symbolHeight: 320
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                    this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Sales per employee',
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [[0,0,10],[0,1,19],[0,2,8],[0,3,24],[0,4,67],[1,0,92],[1,1,58],[1,2,78],[1,3,117],[1,4,48],[2,0,35],[2,1,15],[2,2,123],[2,3,64],[2,4,52],[3,0,72],[3,1,132],[3,2,114],[3,3,19],[3,4,16],[4,0,38],[4,1,5],[4,2,8],[4,3,117],[4,4,115],[5,0,88],[5,1,32],[5,2,12],[5,3,6],[5,4,120],[6,0,13],[6,1,44],[6,2,88],[6,3,98],[6,4,96],[7,0,31],[7,1,1],[7,2,82],[7,3,32],[7,4,30],[8,0,85],[8,1,97],[8,2,123],[8,3,64],[8,4,84],[9,0,47],[9,1,114],[9,2,31],[9,3,48],[9,4,91]],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'black',
                style: {
                    textShadow: 'none'
                }
            }
        }]

    });
});
</script>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Apply scroll property true in yaxis `scrollbar: {enabled: true}` and
>   add `zoomType: 'xy'` in chart object.

```
 var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            type: 'heatmap',
            marginTop: 40,
            marginBottom: 40,
            renderTo: 'container',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },


        title: {
            text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas', 'Maria', 'Leon', 'Anna', 'Tim', 'Laura'],
            min:2
        },

        yAxis: {
            categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
            title: null,
            scrollbar: {
             enabled: true
           }


        },
       scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
       },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 0,
            minColor: '#FFFFFF',
            maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        },

        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            layout: 'vertical',
            margin: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            symbolHeight: 320
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                    this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Sales per employee',
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [[0,0,10],[0,1,19],[0,2,8],[0,3,24],[0,4,67],[1,0,92],[1,1,58],[1,2,78],[1,3,117],[1,4,48],[2,0,35],[2,1,15],[2,2,123],[2,3,64],[2,4,52],[3,0,72],[3,1,132],[3,2,114],[3,3,19],[3,4,16],[4,0,38],[4,1,5],[4,2,8],[4,3,117],[4,4,115],[5,0,88],[5,1,32],[5,2,12],[5,3,6],[5,4,120],[6,0,13],[6,1,44],[6,2,88],[6,3,98],[6,4,96],[7,0,31],[7,1,1],[7,2,82],[7,3,32],[7,4,30],[8,0,85],[8,1,97],[8,2,123],[8,3,64],[8,4,84],[9,0,47],[9,1,114],[9,2,31],[9,3,48],[9,4,91]],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'black',
                style: {
                    textShadow: 'none'
                }
            }
        }]

    });
```

Hope so it helps you !

Comment: you are awesome Saurabh. this worked for me. we need to add min attribute as well to the y-axis. something like this min:5.